# How to trim down date to example 2014-10-10?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-online, date-time, datepicker

How can i trim down date from this `Fri Oct 31 2014 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Västeuropa, normaltid)` to this 2014-10-31 on my `get_fieldValues` i think i can use

`.setDate.getDate()+ 1).toISOString().substr(0, 10);`

this is my fieldValues string

```
$('#GEN_4').val(fieldV.GEN_4_File_Prio);
```

have tried some combinations but didn't get it to work

[image]

**Tried this**
should i really have to use `Fri Oct 31 2014 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Västeuropa, normaltid)`

var d = new Date;

```
$('#GEN_4').val((fieldV.GEN_4_File_Prio.d.getFullYear() + '-' + d.getMonth()+1 + '-' + d.getDate()));

var d = new Date($('#GEN_4').val(fieldV.GEN_4_File_Prio));


$('#GEN_4').d.getFullYear() + '-' + d.getMonth()+1 + '-' + d.getDate();
```

**UPDATE 2**
Don't get it to work

[image]

Comment: Have you tried [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) ?

Comment: You should pass the `get_fieldValues` date value to the `new Date(..);` object

Comment: var d = new Date($('#GEN_4').val(fieldV.GEN_4_File_Prio)); like this?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
var d = new Date('Fri Oct 31 2014 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Västeuropa, normaltid)');
alert(d.getFullYear() + '-' + d.getMonth()+1 + '-' + d.getDate());
```

**Updated based on comment**

```
//Assuming fieldV.GEN_4_File_Prio has a valid date string
var d = new Date(fieldV.GEN_4_File_Prio);
$('#GEN_4').val(d.getFullYear() + '-' + d.getMonth()+1 + '-' + d.getDate());
```

Comment: that worked but i needs to be plus 1 hour so it can work in both sweden and finland

Comment: and it's shows 2014-9-31 but it should be 2014-10-31

Comment: `getMonth()` starts at 0, for the fun of it. Just do ` + (d.getMonth() + 1) + ...`. Note the parentheses here, they are important.

Comment: @linkan94 i have updated the answer

Comment: don't get it to work is this rigth o near right 
    var d = new Date;
    $('#GEN_4').val((fieldV.GEN_4_File_Prio.d.getFullYear() + '-' + d.getMonth()+1 + '-' + d.getDate()));

Comment: You need to pass the string to the Date object..Check the first line of code in my answer.

Comment: getting this "NaN-NaN1-NaN" i use jQuery datepicker if that have somthing to do with it?

Comment: Its because `fieldV.GEN_4_File_Prio` is not a valid date object. You should pass the string value `Fri Oct 31 2014 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Västeuropa, normaltid)`. From where you are getting this value?

Comment: when i choose date it is 2014-10-31 but when i open my item from sharepoint i get it like this Fri `Oct 31 2014 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Västeuropa, normaltid)`

Comment: I will be back soon

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
var d = fieldV.GEN_4_File_Prio;
d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);

$('#GEN_4').val(d.toISOString().substr(0, 10));
```